# Artifactory Remote Repositories - does it keep files deleted remotely?

Tags: artifactory

A repository I use regularly deletes old version of deb packages as it releases new ones, which is very annoying as it breaks our builds until we can bump the package version in our config management.

I was hoping that the Remote Repositories feature would let me create a cache that keeps packages in it even though the original repository has deleted them.

Does Artifactory Remote Repositories delete files when they are deleted from the original repository?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is NO, Artifactory will not delete the files if the remote repository deleted the files. Now there is a scenario that Artifactory will clean unused artifacts BUT only if the Admin choose to and I will explain. In the Artifactory UI --> Admin --> Remote repositories --> Repository configuration --> Advanced tab, you have a checkbox named "Unused Artifacts Cleanup Period". By default, this field is empty which means no cleanup. Unless the Admin change this field nothing should be deleted automatically by any Artifactory process.

Comment: We have this exact use case (reproducible builds!) and it makes us consider adding something like `apt-cache`, although central Artifactory would be preferable. Our understanding is that Artifactory mirrors also the index of a remote repository, so whenever a package-version is unpublished by the remote repository, it becomes unaddressable/dangling in Artifactory. Is there a checkbox to make the index append-only? We are on Artifactory Professional 6.14.2 rev 61402900